# Find relation between Fourier coefficient of $ f(x) $ and $ \overline{f\left(x\right)} $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C} $ be integrable and periodic with period $ 2\pi $.
I have to find relation between Fourer coefficients of $ h\left(x\right)=\overline{f\left(x\right)} $ and $ f(x) $

Here's what Ive tried:

$ \tilde{h}\left(k\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}\overline{f\left(x\right)}e^{-ikx}dx $

Now what I want to do is this:

$ \tilde{h}\left(k\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}\overline{f\left(x\right)}e^{-ikx}dx=\overline{\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(x\right)e^{ikx}dx}=\overline{\tilde{f}\left(-k\right)} $

But I cannot justify that for complex function $ g $ the following equallity holds:

$ \intop_{a}^{b}\overline{g\left(x\right)}dx=\overline{\intop_{a}^{b}g\left(x\right)dx} $.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $ \int {g(x) \mathrm{d}x} = \int {a(x) \mathrm{d}x } + i \int {b(x) \mathrm{d}x} $, where $ a(x) = \mathrm{Re}(g(x)) $ and $ b(x) = \mathrm{Im}(g(x)) $.  Apply this definition to $ \bar{g}(x) = a(x) - i b(x) $.